# Git time out error when building pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a simple Jenkins file, created a jenkins pipeline job and linked to my git repo, it seems like the build success, but there are a lot of info says 'time out', can anyone tell me what's going on?

Eventually I want to trigger one build in jenkins after pushing to gitlab and get a version tag on master branch (now I'm testing with develop branch).

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@xxxxxxxxxx.git
 > git init /jenkins/..../-test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@xxxxxxxxxx.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH Key for GIT User xxx
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@xxxxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@xxxxxxxxxx.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@xxxxxxxxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@xxxxxxxxxx.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH Key for GIT User xxx
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@xxxxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Commit message: "jenkinsfile test"
 > git rev-list --no-walk xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Stage 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 2)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Stage 2
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: The timeout should not worry you. It is just a short wait.

Comment: @mkemmerz But when I check the description, it says'Build stability: 3 out of the last 5 builds failed.' and in the output console, it says 'Finished: SUCCESS', and how can I trigger the build automatically?

Comment: This is a lot at once and I am not sure what exactly you are asking now? Can you concrete your original question?

Comment: yeah sorry, original question is why it says 3 of 5 builds failed, but in the output console, it says 'Finished: SUCCESS', why is that and how can I tell which build failed? Thanks.

Comment: The build you posted in your question was a success. This sucess is only 1 of the last 5 builds you executed in your pipeline. If you go one level above your pipeline you should be able how many builds were executed and also which failed and which were a success.

Comment: ok I get it, means this single build is successful, and for the next question, how I can trigger it after every commit&push?

Comment: This is a very generic question. You usually want a Webhook for it. Simply google it I am sure you will find a tutorial for your scm